# Failed to send jdwp-handshake response :Broken Pipe

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using recycler view to parse some dummy api in the layout but i got the error

```
2019-07-10 22:27:40.723 31746-31775/?: Failed to send jdwp-handshake response.: Broken pipe
2019-07-10 22:27:42.063 31746-31746/E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-07-10 22:28:00.077 31746-31746/ E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-07-10 22:28:03.187 31746-31746/E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-07-10 22:28:10.987 31746-31746/ E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the adapter attached with the recycler view and if everything was fine then restart the ADB might this will work and if the problem continues then try to post some code.

Comment: Adapter was correct and layout too. I don't understand but when i shifted the code to my new project then worked for me :)  ,   Btw Thanks